# api security implementation php

Tags: php, security, api

I have a site that allow users to check their statistics (number of file uploaded, how many files they have, quotas, type of access etc...)

I create a section on my site: api.domain.com

This can be access via curl or a web browser since I am returning a json object or xml (depending on the user prefs)

My question is this: should I restrict the access using a user/pass or should I create a hash of the user file?

for example:

**scenario 1:**

The user create a php curl that sends user and pass via post or the curl auth and get back the results, parse it etc...

For me this is secure but the user has to maintain his script if they change their pass

**scenario 2**

The user access a file like: `api.domain.com/j355HGssgf3HESAjh45jusf4325GSj5hbsHhdh5HGHFS3732he4548475wbe3447nSNe5XfgjhGJ` and then access the data

This one, nothing to maintain

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's my thoughts on this.

If you return a page not found or an error message (with a good 200 OK status) when a request is made to your page, it might send to bots or UN-trustable people a clue on what can they get and try again and again and again ...

On the other hand, if you send a access denied, like a 401, or better a 500 error code to simulate a server error, these bots or UN-trustable people might go away for good.

I will say the user/password method is a little more secure in this case.

Now, would you trust simply entering a big string (like scenario 2) when you check your mail? or your bank account information?

Answer (score 37):

If it was me I would give each account the ability to create a unique api key,

```
api.domain.com/?key=<API.KEY>
```

for more security measure you could make it only accept connection via the post method with the api key. If contacted via get then show an error etc.

Then if they change their pass/username it won't affect their api key

Comment: But what if someone stole your api key? I'm searching some info on this argument because I have 2 server and I want to comunicate via POST some sensible information. But I don't understand, I ca n use an API for retrieve the information, but if someone sniff the call can retrieve sensible info with the api key

Comment: If it is sensitive information, I would use ssl and encrypt the data, decrypt on the other end. If you know an api key has been stolen re-generate a new one :)